# How to run cucmber test from command line and in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, command-line, cucumber

i have created a cucumber framework using Java and Maven. i execute cukesRunner.java locally in eclipse. now i wanted to execute it command line and thru jenkins. could some one please guide me.

Comment: Please add an example + the code you use in the command line.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

cd to your project direct (the one containing pom.xml) and type

```
mvn test
```

Your runner class ends in Test, right?  E.g. RunCukeTest.java

Comment: You can override the @CucumberOptions by adding -Dcucumber.options="..." after mvn test.

Comment: You can also look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193307/how-to-translate-maven-cucumber-jvm-junit-cucumberoptions-to-eclipse-run-co)